# Rewriting behaves differently in .htaccess vs vhost

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using following chunk of instructions to rewrite www to non www url:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I place it in .htaccess file, it works fine.

If I place it in vhost file, after rewriting two forward slashes are added to the host, for example www.domain.com will become domain.com//

Am I missing something?

Also, is it worth placing all .htaccess content in vhost performancewise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RewriteRule` is behaving as the docs say.

There is a difference in what `RewriteRule` matches against when in `VirtualHost` context & `Directory & .htaccess` context.

From [RewriteRule Directive <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> What is matched?
>
> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that lead the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).
>
> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

So, when in `VirtualHost` the server in not in a `directory` context so prefix `/` will not be removed. Also remember when matching with `RewriteRule` in `VirtualHost` context, the pattern will always begin with `/`.

So, your `RewriteRule` Should be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

in `VirtualHost` context.

---

*Also, is it worth placing all .htaccess content in vhost performancewise?*

Yes, Definitely. One reason is that, no file (`.htaccess`) will be read every time you are accessing a page.

Comment: Thank you for very informative answer with excellent solution. I really appreciate your help.